# How to pass in a LINQ statement as a lambda

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Im hoping this isnt too basic a question- I have looked at similar questions but cant seem to understand, so Im reaching out for help.

Im using a repository pattern that I want to make generic - here is what I have for the generic:

```
    static public IQueryable<T> Get(Func<IQueryable<T>> pred, uint page=0, uint pageSize=10)
    {
         return pred()
                .Skip((int)(page * pageSize))
                .Take((int)pageSize);
    }
```

So I want to call it, but get an "has invalid arguments" with whatever lambda I try.

If I declare a method that returns an IQueryable and pass it in as the first parameter, that works- no compile error.  Im stumped.

Please help?  what is the correct way to call this with a lambda?  Or, if my generic is out of whack, how best to declare it?  I assumed a Func that returns an IQueryable would be best...

Comment: It would really help if you could show us some of the lambda expressions which have failed...

Comment: Where from generic type T shoudl come to get() method? Is it declared on a class level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, rather taking in a `Func<IQueryable<T>>,` you just take the `IQueryable<T>` and work with that directly.

```
static public IQueryable<T> Get<T>(IQueryable<T> source, uint page=0, uint pageSize=10) 
{ 
     return source 
            .Skip((int)(page * pageSize)) 
            .Take((int)pageSize); 
}
```

Comment: Well, it appears I was an idiot (which I had predicted to myself)  :-)

Comment: Well, it appears I was an idiot :-)
Im kinda new to lambdas, so cant yet pick out mistakes. Since the query needed no parameters, I did not include "() =>" at the beginning of all my linq attempts.  adding "() =>" made it all work.   But I did learn that a delegate was not required as per Jim's comment - I have changed it to be just an IQueryable, and things look better now - thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Get is missing the T generic

```
static public IQueryable<T> Get<T>(Func<IQueryable<T>> pred, uint page = 0, uint pageSize = 10)
        {
            return pred()
                   .Skip((int)(page * pageSize))
                   .Take((int)pageSize);
        }
```